# Is there any remote desktop software accessible via a browser for linux?

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, remote-access

I want to be able to connect to a linux server with a gui using something similar to x forwarding or no machine's nx client, except have the option for the client to be any browser with no plugins required (i.e. from an ipad/internet cafe pc/friends pc). Is there any software in existence that supports this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be looking for [NX web player](http://www.nomachine.com/web-player.php).

Comment: That appears to be from NX 4.0 which isn't released yet or am I missing something?

Comment: @Obsidian: no, I missed that. Well, I'll leave my answer, hopefully it'll become true one day. But go with the VNC recommendations.

Comment: Great discovery, did not know. It will be very useful to me to manage certain machines.. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

VNC can serve up a Java-based client.  Most browsers have Java enabled.  Just make sure you secure access very well.

Answer (score 1):

The x11vnc program can do what you want.  However, I have found that the web-viewer, while functional, was almost unusably slow.  Also, it is a desktop-sharing or desktop-display system rather than a remote-access system; whatever you can see on the remote access system is visible on the actual console.  This means anyone physically at the computer can see, or potentially can access, anything you can.

Answer (score 1):

X2go has a web accessible interface, but alas it does require a plugin of some form.